# In perl, how can I tee output to stdout and a file for system() return vals?

Tags: perl, stdout, stderr, tee

I'm successfully using
[`IO::Tee`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Tee)
to tee print messages to both stdout and a log file. I'd like to also be able to capture and tee stdout and stderr from a system() commands to the same file.

I tried various combinations of redirection and/or pipes with no luck

Simple script witha few commented out failed attempts...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use IO:Tee;

my $teelog = "tee.log"
open my $tee, ">", $teelog or die "open tee failed.\n";
my $tee = new IO:Tee(\*STDOUT, $tee);

print $tee "First line in log\n";

# This command should work.  I want the date to go to screen and tee.log
#system("date | tee -a ${teelog}");  <- nothing goes to tee.log
#system("date >& ${teelog}") <- clobbers tee.log
#system("date >& $tee") <- generates syntax errors


# This command should fail.  I want error msg to go to screen and tee.log
#system("jibberish | tee -a ${teelog}"); <- nothing goes to tee.log
#system("jibberish >& ${teelog}") <- clobbers tee.log
system("kibberish >& $tee") <- generates syntax errors

print $tee "Last line in log\n";

exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl is buffering output to the `$tee` filehandle and the cursor position of `$tee` is not adjusted after you make a `system` call that writes to the same file, so it is likely that Perl is overwriting whatever output the `system` call writes to the file.

A sequence of calls like this is safer. You may be able to be more concise with more judicious seeking and flushing.

```
use IO:Tee;
my $teelog = "tee.log"
open my $tee, ">", $teelog or die "open tee failed.\n";
$tee = new IO:Tee(\*STDOUT, $tee);
print $tee "First line in log\n";
close $tee;

system("date | tee -a ${teelog}");
system("jibberish 2>&1 | tee -a ${teelog}");

open $tee, ">>", $teelog or die "open tee failed.\n";  # append mode
$tee = new IO:Tee(\*STDOUT, $tee);

print $tee "Last line in log\n";

exit;
```

Comment: Thank You mob for this explanation and suggestion.

I also found another way using capture_exec in  IO:CaptureOutput.  I tested it with a sub that looks like this....

    sub tee_sys_cmd {
        (my $cmd) = @_;

        print $tee "Executing... \"$cmd\"\n";
        my ($stdout, $stderr, $success, $exit_code) = capture_exec($cmd);
 print $tee "$stdout\n$stderr\n";

        return;
    }

This seems to work too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You mob for this explanation and suggestion.

I also found another way using capture_exec in  IO:CaptureOutput.  I tested it with a sub that looks like this....

```
sub tee_sys_cmd {
    (my $cmd) = @_;

    print $tee "Executing... \"$cmd\"\n";
    my ($stdout, $stderr, $success, $exit_code) = capture_exec($cmd);
print $tee "$stdout\n$stderr\n";

    return;
}
```

This seems to work too.

Answer (score -1):

You're discarding the status returned by `system`, so I would use backticks instead:

```
print $tee `date`
```